# Удалённый комментарий с тревогой

Tags: поддержка, история-тревог

Я отметил комментарий тревогой. Через некоторое время его удалили. Считается ли это **полезной тревогой**. Т.е. увеличивается ли счётчик полезных тревог в ЛК?

Comment: Просто посматривайте в свой профиль на закладку активность -- там есть счётчик тревог (общий и полезный) и можно провалиться внутрь, чтобы посмотреть, какой итог был у конкретной тревоги.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current